# code smell - select max(numeroProntuario)+1, mas como consertar isso?

Tags: mysql, estilo-de-codificação

Tenho uma tabela `Paciente` mysql, nela eu tenho a coluna `id`, `nome`, `numeroProntuario` etc. Essa coluna `numeroProntuario` é definida pelo incremento de +1 resultante do `select max(numeroProntuario)` (código legado, não me julguem).
Agora, eu estou implementando uma lista de espera, e estou integrando com essa tabela, ao notar esse problema, pensei em usar o mesmo número do id no número do prontuário. Mas não encontrei nada nesse sentido e eu ainda não posso mudar os registros anteriores.

**Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu conserto isso, ou não tem conserto e é melhor tocar assim mesmo?**

Tabela Paciente:

```
id      numeroProntuario    nome
5565    5548                ANA
5566    5549                PRISCILA
5567    5550                MIRIAN 
5568    5551                ALEXANDRE
5569    5552                JACONIAS 
5570    5553                KASSIO 
5571    5554                KEROLY 
5572    5555                ALEX
```

Comment: Você quer parar de usar o select max(numeroProntuario)+1?

Comment: eu acho que isso é uma má prática, então se possível sim. Eu gostaria de arrumar isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, 
Valida essa solução: 
Alterar a coluna para auto_increment e setar o valor atual dela:

```
ALTER TABLE Paciente MODIFY COLUMN numeroProntuario INT auto_increment;
ALTER TABLE Paciente AUTO_INCREMENT = select max(numeroProntuario)+1 from Paciente;
```

**UPDATE:**

Como a tabela pode ser somente 1 columa auto_increment, o incremento do valor pode ser feito via trigger e o select removida da aplicação:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SetNumeroProntuario BEFORE INSERT ON Paciente 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.numeroProntuario = select max(numeroProntuario)+1 from Paciente;
END
```

Comment: Já tentei, mas por via das dúvidas tentei novamente: 

ALTER TABLE Paciente  MODIFY COLUMN numeroProntuario INT auto_increment Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key 0.047 sec.


E tem mais, eu não posso perder ou modificar os registros anteriores.

Comment: esse select max(numeroProntuario)+1, é executado na aplicação.

Comment: Entendi o problema, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: É isso mesmo. Vou fazer mais uns testes aqui, mas acredito isso sirva.  

Só uma coisa, eu quero deixar o prontuario, igual ao id. Então fiz tipo isso: 

**SET NEW.numeroProntuario = select max(id) from Paciente;**

Comment: Se o prontuario vai ser igual ao id, testa se assim funciona:

SET NEW.numeroProntuario = NEW.id;